# CGI script receiving unreliable input from HTML form: why?

Tags: python, input, cgi

Is there a limit to the amount of text that can be uploaded to Python cgi script on a server via an HTML  or ?

I'm trying to upload a list of 5,000 ten-digit numbers (to simulate a list of phone numbers to be used in network analysis) via a webpage to my CGI script for processing.  But the client-server relationship is unreliable.  Sometimes the CGI script receives all 5,000 numbers, but sometimes only a portion of them.  Neither the server nor the CGI script throws an exception: the CGI script just thinks that only 2,800 (or whatever) items were sent instead of the 5,000 that actually were.

I can't figure out what makes this happen.  Same unpredictability occurs when I change the input method on the webpage to input type='textarea' and just cut-and-paste the data.  I've tried adding time.sleep() pauses at various places in the CGI script, etc, but nothing seems to influence it consistently positively or negatively.  I'm using the same sample data set every time.

Client and server are both on my laptop (127.0.0.1:80) and nothing else is running on the server.  Code for the server, HTML front-end, and CGI script are pasted below.  I'd be grateful for any insight!

```
#SERVER#
#!python3
import os, sys
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
webdir = 'C:\(...)\webapps'
port   = 80
os.chdir(webdir)
srvraddr = ("", port)
srvrobj  = HTTPServer(srvraddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvrobj.serve_forever()
print('ready to go')

<!--HTML FRONT END-->
<html>
<title>Interactive Page</title>
<body>
<p>
<form method=POST action = 'cgi-bin/cgi101_Jan.py' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Select a file:
<input type = file name = upFile>
<p><input type = submit>
</form>
</body>

#CGI SCRIPT#
#!python3
import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
upFile = form['upFile'].file
print('Content-type: text/html\n')
print('<title>Reply Page</title>')
fh = upFile.readlines()
for line in fh:
    print(str(line)+'<br>')
```